# When adding an index on multiple columsn in rails, two indexes are created. How do i prevent that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

So I am currently assigned a task in Ruby which I have never used before and I've run into a very strange problem. I have this migration for a model message, which has an index on chat_id and number.

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :chat, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.integer :number, null: false
      t.string :body
      #t.index [:chat_id, :number] doesn't work
      t.timestamps
    end
    #add_index :messages, [:chat_id, :number] #doesn't work either

  end
end
```

The end schema of both those migrations when running rails db:migrate is this

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "chat_id", null: false
    t.integer "number", null: false
    t.string "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["chat_id", "number"], name: "index_messages_on_chat_id_and_number"
    t.index ["chat_id"], name: "index_messages_on_chat_id"
  end
```

Obviously, the second created index is completely useless. How do I prevent this from occuring and create only one index when migrating?

Ruby 2.7.6
Rails 5.2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is adding the index you wish to remove. It accepts an `index` parameter which defaults to `true`, change it to:

```
t.references :chat, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: false
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thanks alot. This behaviour is quite weird though. I believe that some servers did have this property by default, but that is not the case now. Strange of rails to set it to true by default.